# WhereIn no Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando implementar uma *query* com o uso do `whereIn` no Eloquent, mas sempre gera um erro, alguém saberia me passar uma orientação sobre?

Meu código está assim:

```
$result = DB::query()->select('permissao')
                     ->whereIn('id_permissoes', $variavel_com_os_valores)
                     ->get();
```

Já tentei passar a variável dentro de um *array* também `[$variavel_com_os_valores]`, mas sempre gera erro, alguém sabe se existe outra forma de implementar um `where in`? Mesmo que seja no SQL puro `SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE id IN ($variavel)`?

Quando não gera uma mensagem de erro só trás uma resposta de retorno, ou seja, ele só consegue verificar somente o primeiro número que está contida na variável, digamos que na varável contenha `1,2,3` só verifica no primeiro número, no caso o 1.

Quando gera a mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   D:\PROJETOS\clinicamedica\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Builder.php
>   on line 775
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   D:\PROJETOS\clinicamedica\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
>   on line 250 and defined in
>   D:\PROJETOS\clinicamedica\vendor\illuminate\database\Grammar.php:135
>   Stack trace: #0
>   D:\PROJETOS\clinicamedica\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php(250):
>   Illuminate\Database\Grammar->parameterize('1, 2') #1
>   D:\PROJETOS\clinicamedica\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php(196):
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar->whereIn(Object(Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder),
>   Array) #2 [internal function]:
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar->Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars{closure}(Array,
>   0) #3
>   D:\PROJETOS\clinicamedica\vendor\illuminate\support\Collection.php(743):
>   array_map(Object(Closure), Array, Array) #4
>   D:\PROJETOS\clinicamedica\vendor\illuminate\database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php(197):
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->map(Objec in
>   D:\PROJETOS\clinicamedica\vendor\illuminate\database\Grammar.php on
>   line 135`

Comment: Primeiro: `whereIn` espera um `array` como parâmetro, então, sim, você precisa passá-lo como `array`. A questão agora é: Qual é o valor de `$variavel_com_os_valores`? É uma *string*? Se for, você precisará dar o `explode` nela.

Comment: `$variavel_com_os_valores` tem o que? e sempre terá esse valor ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, resolvi aplicando o explode....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do [laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses), o método "whereIn" deve receber um array como parâmetro, mesmo que seja apenas um valor.

```
$result = DB::query()->select( 'permissao' )
                     ->whereIn('id_permissoes', $array )
                     ->get();
```